# Returning SELECT results from a function as a JSON (Postgres)

Tags: postgresql

I have a plpgsql function and a complex nested SELECT query and I'd like to return the result table of the query as a JSON. How would I go about doing this? I have something like this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE selectRESULTS AS
 /*some long, complicated, and nested SELECT query
 .............
 ..............
 */
RETURN array_to_json(array_agg(selectResults));
```

---

Edit: I added additional specifications after trying one of the solutions

Using Pozs' method:

```
RETURN (SELECT json_agg(selectResults) FROM selectResults);
```

I do get a json. However it's nested with extra arrays which makes the inner object harder to access.

Currently I get

```
[['[{"someKey": someValue}, etc]']]
```

Is there any way to get rid of the two outer arrays so that instead of using

`somejson[0][0][0]["someKey"]` to acess `someValue`, I can just use `someJson[0]["someKey"]`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, you have an error in your syntax; you need a `SELECT` to use aggregate functions, like `array_agg`. You can use the `array()` constructor too:

```
-- do NOT use these, these are far from optimal

RETURN array_to_json(array(SELECT selectResults FROM selectResults));
-- or
RETURN (SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(selectResults)) FROM selectResults);
```

But [`json_agg(...)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) does effectively the same as `array_to_json(array_agg(...))` but faster:

```
RETURN (SELECT json_agg(selectResults) FROM selectResults);
```

**Note:** I used `selectResults` to select the whole row of `selectResults` table, but if you have only 1 column in it, you can use directly that.

However, you may not need a temporary table at all. If your logic is that simple, you can use a simple `sql` function, like:

```
create function xyz(p1_type, ..., pn_type)
  returns json
  language sql
as $func$
  select json_agg(select_results)
  from (
    /*some SELECT query here
     .............
     use $1 ... $<n> for parameters here,
     or you can name them also within sql functions
     .............
     */
  ) select_results
$func$;
```

Comment: Thanks! I haven't tried this yet but my query is quite complex (heavily nested, performs various calculations, and works with multiple columns) so a simple SQL function may be out of the question.

Comment: Edited my post. Do you happen to have an alternate solution that meets my additional specifications?

Comment: @Teboto it is impossible to tell without any further knowledge about `selectResults`. (The most possible solution is that your data is already in an array) Please provide more details, and don't change the question after every bit of new information. If you have a new problem, post it as a separate question.

Comment: You're right, the problem has to do with my `selectResults`, which is obtained from subqueries. I'll post a new question, thanks.